# Prove that $X\cup A=B\: \Leftrightarrow \:B-A\subset X\subset B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not really good at set-theory exercices and I'm trying to solve this:

$E$ is a set

$X, A, B$ are in $E$

Prove that: $X\cup A=B\: \Leftrightarrow \:B-A\subset X\subset B$ and $A \subset B$

Proving that $X \subset B$ is easy since $X \cup A = B$

However I don't know how to proceed for the rest. Any help?

Comment: Do you see that if $X\cup A=B$, then any element of $B$ that is **not** in $A$ must necessarily be in $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one direction, use distributive properties of union and intersection:

$B\setminus A= (X\cup A)\setminus A= (X\cup A)\cap A^c=(X\cap A^c)\cup (A\cap A^c)=X\setminus A\subset X\subset X\cup A=B$

and so, $B\setminus A\subset X\subset B$.

---

On the other direction, if

$B\setminus A\subset X\subset B$, and $A\subset B$
then
$$B= (B\setminus A)\cup A \subset X\cup A\subset B\cap A\subset B$$

and so, $B=X\cup A$.